# DDOS in Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, ddos

I am currently running two containers on Cloud Run for my web app (React and Nodejs). I have been looking into how to prevent my apps from DDOS. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Most GCP services sit behind Google Front End which mitigates and absorbs many Layer 4 and below attacks, such as SYN floods, IP fragment floods, port exhaustion, etc. I believe it's also the case for Cloud Run but don't have information to confirm that. You can enable HTTP(S) Load Balancing or SSL proxy Load Balancing as it provides this mechanism.
2. Regarding payments due to increased treffic, best way to solve that is to set [API rate-limiting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits) and [Resource Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)
3. [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/)
4. If possible you should isolate your internal traffic from the external world.

Comment: I'd like to second this answer. If #1 is not enough, you can always use #3 (Cloud Armor) by creating a Cloud LB and putting Cloud Run behind it. As for #2, it doesn't apply to Cloud Run. However you can limit max instances on Cloud Run to prevent excess spending during an attack that's not absorbed.

Comment: For #2 you can now use API Gateway (a Cloud Endpoint like but fully manage by google!). Is your website open to unauthenticated users?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes. But I am also thinking if I can make that the backend container (Nodejs) can be accessed by the frontend container.

Comment: I'm not a react fan (even an user, I never develop with it), but AFAIK, it's a JS framework and nothing is processed by the container, all the JS is interpreted by the user browser. Thus, the Frontend container never requests the backend, it's the user browser that request the backend right?

Answer (score 1):

For **Cloud Run**, you should use **a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)** which provides **automatic multi-tier, multi-layer DoS protections** that further reduce the risk of **"any DoS impact"**. In addition, you can use **Cloud Armor** to control access to your Google Cloud Platform resources by creating security policies and also **Cloud Armor** provides **Layer 3 and 4 DoS attack protections** and **layer 7 DoS attack protection(Adaptive Protection)** and **more features(Managed Protection Plus)**.

*In detail, **a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)** is based on **Google Front End(GFE)** which provides **automatic multi-tier, multi-layer DoS protections** that further reduce the risk of **any DoS impact**.

Actually, **Google** doesn't clearly mention which layers of DoS attacks **a global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)** can protect from. **Google** only says **"any DoS impact"**. I guess **"any DoS impact"** can be layer 3, 4 and 7 DoS attacks.

I referred to:

[Choosing a load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer)

[feedbackGoogle Infrastructure Security Design Overview](https://cloud.google.com/security/infrastructure/design)

[DDoS protection and mitigation on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf)

[Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor)